# In css, how do I make things stay positioned in a way that nothing will push it on the page

Tags: css, positioning

So, I tried doing position:absolute, but whenever I place something new, (eg a div) the other div gets pushed down.

Eg. without other div

Box

With other div

other div

box

Thanks :D

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed`?  This takes the element out of the 'flow of the page.

Comment: What are you asking? `position:absolute` - when used properly - will achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried search the net for a good tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the CSS rule is not ovewritten? (Check this with a browser code inspector, such as *Firefox's Firebug* or *Opera's Dragonfly*)
Additionally, If you want the div to be put on a place despite srolling,
use

`position: fixed`

instead. This will keep your object on a fixed place in the page.

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote up and/or select this as best answer, I would appreciate this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`.

If you want the element to be stuck on the screen no matter how to scroll, you can use `position:fixed`.  Make sure that your `top` & `left` or `bottom` & `right` are set appropriately. Also make sure that the `z-index` is set appropriately, so no other element is covering it.

`position:absolute;` DOES depend on the parents of that element.  If a parent of that element is positioned, then the absolute positioning will position the element within that element.

do you have examples of your code?